# <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'> ERROR IN PLAYBOOK.WHAT IS WRONG WITH MAIN.YML FILE

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

- Create a file named simplefile.txt - write a task in the main.yml file in present in fresco_when\tasks folder.- the task is to move the created simplefile.txt file to created directory i.e move the create file to /home/user/test folder.- move only if the file doesn't exist. using when in the playbook

I created a text file and then wrote this main.yml file:

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: copy a file, but do not copy if the file already exists
    command: cp challenge/fresco_when/defaults/simplefile.txt /home/usr/test/ creates=simplefile.txt

I got this error :

ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_when/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may

be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- hosts: localhost

  ^ here

SCORE:0%

Please let me know what is wrong with the code

Comment: Did you start your playbook file with `---`?

Comment: You're problem maybe its t he indetation. Edit your question with the correct style of your playbook.

Comment: @dgw although a YAML should ideally start with `---`  you can perfectly go without if you don't have directives nor multiple documents in your YAML.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64914692/edit) and fix the formatting

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on the path in your question, it appears you have used the playbook structure for a tasks file within that playbook

For clarity, *playbooks* need to specify the hosts to which they will apply, but tasks within a playbook are going to apply to all the hosts in that play *(err, more or less)*

The contents of `tasks/*.yml` inside a playbook directory should be a yaml list consisting only of tasks (`- command:`, `- debug:`, that kind of thing), and **not** `- hosts:`)

---

Separately, while this isn't what you asked, you are re-implementing [`- copy:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) as ansible is likely going to warn you about when you run that task

The ansible-y way of doing that is:

```yaml
- name: copy a file, but do not copy if the file already exists
  copy:
    src: challenge/fresco_when/defaults/simplefile.txt
    dest: /home/usr/test/simplefile.txt
```